# Ionic2 ionic native camera

Tags: ionic2, ionic-native

I get  build error using ionic-native module as it always gives me the following error

```
 Error: ./src/pages/admin-home/admin-home.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ionic-native' in
            'E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\src\pages\admin-home' resolve 'ionic-native' in
            'E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\src\pages\admin-home' Parsed request is a module using description file:
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/admin-home) Field 'browser' doesn't
            contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\package.json
            (relative path: ./src/pages/admin-home) resolve as module looking for modules in
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules using description file:
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
            valid alias configuration after using description file: E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\package.json (relative
            path: ./node_modules) using description file:
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\package.json (relative path: .) no extension Field
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native is not a file .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a
            valid alias configuration E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.ts doesn't exist .js Field
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't
            contain a valid alias configuration E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.json doesn't
            exist as directory existing directory using path:
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index using description file:
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\package.json (relative path: ./index) no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't
            contain a valid alias configuration E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index.ts doesn't
            exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't
            contain a valid alias configuration E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index.json
            doesn't exist [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native]
            [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.ts]
            [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.js]
            [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.json]
            [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index]
            [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index.ts]
            [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index.js]
            [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index.json] @ ./src/pages/admin-home/admin-home.ts
            13:0-46 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts
Error: ./src/pages/admin-home/admin-home.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ionic-native' in 'E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\src\pages\admin-home'
resolve 'ionic-native' in 'E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\src\pages\admin-home'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/admin-home)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/admin-home)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules
        using description file: E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native is not a file
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                using path: E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index
                  using description file: 

    E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\package.json (relative path: ./index)
                        no extension
                          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                          E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index doesn't exist
                        .ts
                          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                          E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index.ts doesn't exist
                        .js
                          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                          E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index.js doesn't exist
                        .json
                          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                          E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native\index.json doesn't exist
    [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native]
    [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.ts]
    [E:\Work\myBabyFeed\myBabyFeed\node_modules\ionic-native.js]
```

I have updated the packages file with latest version of ionic-native but still get the error.
anyone can help please

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/issues/140

Comment: Did you check  this http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-native-3-x/?

Comment: yes , but it has nothing with my issue, i am using ionic native with cordova camera plugin, and i am doing exactly like guide telling us

Comment: thanks i find the error , ionic-native has been depricated, no we need to use @ionic-native/camera , and core separatly,